# How to pass error using session

Tags: php, session, error-handling

How to pass this error to the next page using session. I tried passing it but it always get the last error. Why?

```
$err = "You forgot to enter you password";
$err  = "Your forgot to enter you username";
$err = "You forgot to enter you telephone number";
```

I try pass this one like this. With this one it give me the last error. Why is it? I added also a session start above this two pages.

```
Page1. php
$_SESSION['errMsg'] = $err;

page2.php 
$getError = $_SESSION['errMsg'];
echo $getError;
```

Comment: "the last error" --- what does this mean?

Comment: It gives me the you forgot to enter the telephone number. That is last error means.

Comment: and what should be there instead?

Comment: @zerkms it should be say you forgot to enter your username. Not the telephone number

Comment: how would php know that it should display that exact message?

Answer (score 2):

You're overwriting your $err variable each time you add an error. You need to concatenate or make an array of errors to pass to the next page.

```
$err .= "You forgot to enter you password";
$err .= " Your forgot to enter you username";
$err .= " You forgot to enter you telephone number";

$_SESSION['errMsg'] = $err;

page2.php 
$getError = $_SESSION['errMsg'];
echo $getError;
```

or

```
$err = array(
    "You forgot to enter you password",
    "Your forgot to enter you username",
    "You forgot to enter you telephone number"
);
$_SESSION['errMsg'] = $err;

page2.php 
$getError = implode(' ', $_SESSION['errMsg']);
echo $getError;
```

These examples are *very* basic but should show you how to solve your problem.

Comment: thank you. I already try that one. Yes, it is working but I want to pass it using session. Can you help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

You always get the last message? That is because that is the last value you gave your variable! You're always going to get the last one there.

If you need to control it, use an if statement:

```
if(condition==true) {
  $err = "You forgot to enter you password";
} else {
  $err = "You forgot to enter you telephone number";
}
```

You go:

```
Create $err with the value: "You forgot to enter you password";
Update $err to: "Your forgot to enter you username";
Update $err to: "You forgot to enter you telephone number";
```

Whenever you reference `$err`, you are getting the most recent value.

What you probably want to do is this:

```
$err = "First condition";
$err = $err . " " . "Second Condition";
```

That would have `$err` be `First condition Second Condition`.

Comment: Thanks for giving me the answer right away. Yeah, I put that one in and if statement already. But it giving me the last error still.

Comment: @user can you add the code? We can't help you much without your code with the if statement. Thanks!

Comment: @Can you give me your email address I will just send it to you.

Comment: @user no, that is not allowed on SE. If you can't post it in the question, don't expect any help from anyone.

Comment: Can you give me your email address. Please. I guess you have lot of idea..please.

Answer (score 0):

It always gets the "last error" because the way you set it:

```
$err = "You forgot to enter you password";
$err  = "Your forgot to enter you username";
$err = "You forgot to enter you telephone number";
```

Means that the **last** line will **always** be the error message because you **over-write** the `$err` variable.

Simply throw in a condition:

```
if(THIS ERROR) {
    $err = "You forgot to enter you password";
} else if(THAT ERROR) {
    $err = "You forgot to enter you telephone number";
} else {
    $err to: "You forgot to enter you telephone number";
}
```

Or a simple `switch/case`

```
switch($error) {
    case 'mobile';
         $err = "You forgot to enter you password";
         break;
    ///.....etc
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this explanation. I totally understand it. Thanks a lot. GOD BLESS YOU.

Comment: regarding with all of your explanation. my code dont have an else statement all of them are if statement.

Comment: @user3912595 each to their own, if it works as you want it to, then be happy!